# In how many ways can you distribute $3$ chocolates among $2$ kids if you have to give all $3$ of the chocolates to the kids?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can you distribute $3$ chocolates among $2$ kids?
One kid can get none. But we need to give away all $3$ of the chocolates to the $2$ kids.

Why is it wrong to use $3C2$(which gives just one way) when we are distributing $3$ chocolates to $2$ kids?

Can you explain in simple words? Thank you.

Comment: One! You give them all to me!!!

Comment: There are no other conditions. One kid can get zero chocolates too. Could you explain with the help of combinations and use the nCr formula
Thank you

Comment: Are they different chocolates?!

Comment: Are the chocolates identical?

Comment: Yes they are all identical

Comment: If you don't specify what 'different' ways, there are infinitely many: by mail, making a raffle, letting them fight for the chocos, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1$ denote the number of chocolates that are given to the first child; let $x_2$ denote the number of chocolates that are given to the second child.  Since we must distribute all three chocolates to the two children, 
$$x_1 + x_2 = 3$$
The number of ways we can distribute the chocolates to the two children is equal to the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 3$ in the nonnegative integers.  There are four such solutions.  They are $(0, 3)$, $(1, 2)$, $(2, 1)$, and $(3, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

Denote the three chocolates with the symbols %%%, and consider an additional symbol |.

Now move around those symbols, and interpret that the % which end up to the left of | are chocolates given to the first child, and the % which end up to the right of | are given to the second child. For example, one possible permutation is %%|%, which means the first child got 2 chocolates and the second one got 1. |%%% means the second child got all chocolates.

There are $4!$ possible arrangements of the symbols %%%|, but since the $3$ chocolates are identical you need to divide by $3!$ to get all different orderings, which gives:

$${4! \over 3!}=4$$

This is also equivalent to ${4 \choose 1}$ since we're choosing a place for the | in a row formed by three % and a single |.

Comment: Thank you. But can you please show me a way to do it without the % and | symbols?

Comment: The % and | are just a shorthand, we could replace % by the word "chocolate" but the notation quickly becomes messier. You can think of | as a separator between the two kids (this is clearer if you think of two urns instead of two kids). What do you mean "without the % and | symbols"?